# Haskell optimisation: how to stop list from performing allocations?

Tags: haskell, optimization

In this program:

```
module Main where
import Data.IntSet
main = do
   print $ size
         $ {-# SCC "fromAscList" #-} fromAscList
         $ {-# SCC "generate_list" #-} [1..1000]
```

(Compile and run with `stack ghc Main.hs -- -prof -fprof-auto && ./Main +RTS -p`)

I get this output from the GHC profiler (edited for brevity):

```
    total alloc =     202,704 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE   MODULE           SRC                    %time %alloc

generate_list Main             Main.hs:6:40-48          0.0   39.5
fromAscList   Main             Main.hs:(5,38)-(6,48)    0.0   36.2
main          Main             Main.hs:(3,1)-(6,48)     0.0    5.0

                                          individual      inherited
COST CENTRE       MODULE                %time %alloc   %time %alloc

  main            Main                   0.0    0.1     0.0   75.8
   fromAscList    Main                   0.0   36.2     0.0   75.7
    generate_list Main                   0.0   39.5     0.0   39.5
```

This seems to indicate that `[1..a']` is allocating 80Kb (39.5% of 202,704 bytes) over the course of the program, and then `fromAscList` is allocating the same amount again. (One allocation for the input Int, and another for the stored Int?)

Two questions:

1. Are these "real" allocations from `generate_list`, or would it be reusing the same piece of memory repeatedly? (I want to know if heap allocations could be a bottleneck.)
2. If this is repeatedly using the heap, is there a way to instead stream unboxed values 1..1000 directly into `fromAscList`?

Comment: What optimization level is being used?

Comment: It seems the same with and without -O

Comment: what about -O2?

Comment: `stack ghc Test.hs -- -O2 -funbox-strict-fields -prof -fprof-auto` gives the same results

Comment: Cost centers ruin optimization. GHC essentially refuses to optimize code out of or between cost centers, to give more accurate results within the cost centers, but, in this case (and basically whenever you use -fprof-auto) it also confounds the data.

Comment: To be clear, I’m not saying that removing the “generateList” cost center *will* improve allocation (but it *might*), because I’m not sure if fromAscList participates in fusion anyway, but that the measurement will be more accurate without it. If removing it doesn’t do much, you can use a simple “foldr insert empty”, which will definitely fuse the list away, but then you lose whatever fromAscList is supposed to give you. You may also want to look at fromDistinctAscList.

Comment: Those integers are boxed, aren't they? So maybe those are just the allocations of those boxes (from generate_list) and the allocations needed for the internal data of Data.IntSet (fromAscList).

Comment: Utterly trivial stylistic note: making a single statement into a `do` block is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `fromDistinctAscList`, otherwise every next `Int` has to be compared with its predecessor to determine whether to add it or to skip, which must be incurring the overhead you observe. *(Though I have not looked at the source code, it seems a plausible guess that this happens, and we could hardly expect memory to be allocated in an optimal way in such case.)*

Try this code:

```
main = do
   print $ size
         $ {-# SCC "fromDistinctAscList" #-} fromDistinctAscList
         $ {-# SCC "generate_list" #-} [1..1000]
```

The performance that I observe is about 36% better memory-wise. (This figure seems to align with yours.) Here is the relevant section of the profiling report:

```
COST CENTRE            MODULE                SRC                        no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc
....
  main                 ListAlloc             ListAlloc.hs:(5,1)-(8,55)  276          1    0.0    0.2     0.0   62.5
   fromDistinctAscList ListAlloc             ListAlloc.hs:(7,46)-(8,55) 278          1    0.0    1.1     0.0   62.4
    generate_list      ListAlloc             ListAlloc.hs:8:40-55       279          1    0.0   61.2     0.0   61.2
...
```

Concerning the reality of the allocations, I'm not sure I understand the question but, looking at garbage collections with `+RTS -S`, both variants run in almost same memory all along, linearly growing due to the growth of the `IntMap`. It seems all other computations are done in reasonably small constant memory.